# ArrayList lottery game - excess array lists

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have been tinkering with this program for a while, but I still do not know what is wrong. 
My problem is that if I want to get more than 1 ticket it gives me more array lists than expected. I cannot find a pattern as if I enter 2, I get 3, and if I enter 3, I get 6, and if I enter 4, I get back 10.

Input: Amount for how many tickets I want.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayListLottery {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int range = 49, amount = -1, number = 0, choice = -1;
      // ArrayList<Integer> tickets = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> games = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
      do {
         System.out.println("Enter amount of lottery tickets you want");
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
         if (amount < 0) {
            amount = in.nextInt();
         }
         while (amount != 0) {
            System.out.println("Entered while block");  
            for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
               // Create an arraylist for how
               // many tickets i want
               ArrayList<Integer> tickets = new ArrayList<Integer>();
               games.add(tickets);
               for (int k = 0; k < 6; k++) { // Limit the size of a ticket to
                                             // 6
                  if (tickets.size() < 6) {
                     number = (int) (range * Math.random()) + 1;
                     tickets.add(number);
                     Collections.sort(tickets);
                  } else { 
                     break;
                  }
               }// limit for loop to 6 end
            }// arraylist creator end
            amount--;
            System.out.println("Amount is " + amount);
         }//while loop end

         for (List<Integer> i : games) { //print out each ticket
            for (Integer n : i) {
               System.out.print(n + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
         } //print out for-loop end

         games.clear();

         System.out.println("Type 0 to exit, otherwise pick any other number ");
         choice = in.nextInt();
         amount = choice;
      } while (amount != 0);
      System.out.println("Good luck!");
   }
}
```

Comment: I absolutely see a pattern... 1 ticket = 1 list, 2 tickets = 2 lists + 1 list = 3 lists, 3 tickets = 3 lists + 2 lists + 1 list = 6, 4 tickets = 4 lists + 3 lists + 2 lists + 1 list = 10 lists. This behavior is occurring due to the `i < amount` in your first `for` loop. The while loop starts with `amount = 4`, so the `for` loops runs 4 times, generating 4 lists. Then it decreases to `amount = 3`, so the `for` loop runs 3 times... see?

Comment: Ahh I see it now. I have to decrement amount before I enter the while loop.

Comment: There's an even easier fix - your for loop already goes through each ticket, you don't need an extra `while` loop  like Naman said because it's already checking each one. Just use an `if` statement to check that the number entered is greater than 0, and if so run the `for` loop. No need to decrement.

Comment: Or, alternatively, leave the while loop in and take out the for loop.

Comment: Makes sense. Is there a way for me to practice this to avoid my mistakes in the future? Like I couldn't see what was wrong for a good few hours.

Comment: You can check `while` loop, `for` loop documentation for this.

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=java+loop+exercises

Comment: And also you can debug your code in your IDE, most of time that will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Fibonacci number of amount` will be your size of games list.

It is happening because you have applied while as well as for loop for `amount`.

Replace your `while` loop with `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can put

```
amount--;
```

in the for loop which generate the arraylist.

Like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayListLottery {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int range = 49, amount = -1, number = 0, choice = -1;
      // ArrayList<Integer> tickets = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> games = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
      do {
         System.out.println("Enter amount of lottery tickets you want");
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
         if (amount < 0) {
            amount = in.nextInt();
         }
         while (amount != 0) {
            System.out.println("Entered while block");  
            for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
               // Create an arraylist for how
               // many tickets i want
               ArrayList<Integer> tickets = new ArrayList<Integer>();
               games.add(tickets);
               for (int k = 0; k < 6; k++) { // Limit the size of a ticket to
                                             // 6
                  if (tickets.size() < 6) {
                     number = (int) (range * Math.random()) + 1;
                     tickets.add(number);
                     Collections.sort(tickets);
                  } else { 
                     break;
                  }
               }// limit for loop to 6 end
               amount--;
            }// arraylist creator end
            System.out.println("Amount is " + amount);
         }//while loop end

         for (List<Integer> i : games) { //print out each ticket
            for (Integer n : i) {
               System.out.print(n + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
         } //print out for-loop end

         games.clear();

         System.out.println("Type 0 to exit, otherwise pick any other number ");
         choice = in.nextInt();
         amount = choice;
      } while (amount != 0);
      System.out.println("Good luck!");
   }
}
```

Besides that, you can add a breakpoint to step over your program line by line which may make you find the bug quickly.